# Is there an Android equivalent to jQuery's document.ready() function? I want my elements to be finished drawing before I change their value

Tags: android, android-activity

I am changing the value of several RatingBars upon completion of a child activity (inside the onActivityResult() callback).  My problem is that the parent activity has not finished drawing before my RatingBars value-changing code is executed, so I get some funky lag and a half-way completed "animation" before the parent layout has even been displayed.

I'm familiar with the document.ready() function in jQuery, which waits until the DOM is completely ready to commence any script therein.

Is there any way to achieve the same result with Android?  In other words, I need a way to wait until an activity has completely finished drawing itself to the user's screen before some code is executed.

This might be a simple thing in Android, but I'm pretty noob.  Thanks for your time and help.

-Steve

Answer (score 1):

Could you simply put the code in the onResume method which will be called after the views have been set up?? (Not sure if this include getting drawn)

Another possibility is to create a handler and dispatch a method to it at the end of the onCreate method, this will get run on the UI thread but I imagine this won't get processed until the UI thread has finished the more important stuff (i.e. drawing the views)

This is largely just me putting down possible ideas, I know there is a way of achieving this I just can't remember how.